# Firebase e-mail link signin on different devices

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, password-less

I’m developing an Angular app using Firebase Auth and I want to allow my users to log in via email link.

My users will not open the link on the same device as they are trying to log in on.

When my user requests an email link on Device A and then opens that email link on Device B (confirming the email), will he then be logged in on Device A as well as Device B? This is the behavior I want.

If it’s not possible out-of-the-box, is there any custom way of enabling this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this ain't allowed by Firebase

> Firebase Auth requires the user's email address to be provided when completing the sign-in flow. For sign-in to succeed, this email address must match the address to which the sign-in link was originally sent.

[Ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#security_concerns)

Comment: Can someone explain why? How does that add any security benefit?